# Unable to use custom domain for Heroku app

Tags: heroku, dns

I have purchased a domain with a DNS provider – Namecheap for my Heroku app and followed all of the steps given my Heroku and Namecheap for configuring the domain and the DNS target that was given by Heroku with Namecheap. But still my domain is not working, only by free domain provided my Heroku. I have contacted Namecheap and they have told me all of the settings are correct. I am not able to contact Heroku because I'm on the free service, and I have no idea what is missing here.

```
=== robertosullivan Custom Domains
Domain Name          DNS Record Type  DNS Target
───────────────────  ───────────────  
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
robertosullivan.com  ALIAS or ANAME   concentric-cantaloupe- 
koaxxlt4rixetcdacu1ebggn.herokudns.com
```

In the Advanced DNS settings of Namecheap, the CNAME record has a host of `www` and the value is set to the DNS target given above.

I just want my custom domain to work for my app, but when I try to access the domain I'm told by a Heroku message "nothing here yet".

Comment: In the DNS `robertosullivan.com.` maps to `162.255.119.14` and nothing seems to reply at that IP on port 443. For port 80 it redirects to `http://www.robertosullivan.com/` which generates a 404. The `www` record is a CNAME mapped to Heroku.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Patrick. Sorry, this is unfamiliar territory for me. Do you have any suggestions as to what I can do? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use www.robertosullivan.com instead of robertosullivan.com